# How to make a jar in Eclipse that contains HTML files that need to run when the jar is started?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jar

I'm stuck, how should I add HTML files to my project so that when the jar is created and I move it anywhere in my computer, it loads the HTML files when I run the jar.

Comment: you can create a war file for web application. If thats what u want ?

Comment: Is this a web application, a desktop app. or something else?  What is 'the HTML'?  1) The web-app. 2) Help files for the desktop app. 3) ...

Answer (score 2):

You should add them as `src/main/resources` files - these then get packaged into your .jar with your code.

Then you can load them using the `Class` methods `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(Help.class.getClass().getResource("/main/resources/Back24.gif"));                but it still doesn't show up on the frame

Comment: @richarcheto94 - the resource needs to be in the same package within the resources folder as the class on which you are calling `getResource()`. In your case; first, you are calling this on the `Class` class (`Help.class.getClass()` returns `Class` - just use `Help.class.getResource()`; and second if, say, `Help` were in the package `com.richarcheto`, then the resource should be in `resources/com/richarcheto/Back24.gif`. (This is not absolutely necessary, as you can instruct navigation to the resources path, but it's an easy place to start from...)

Answer (score 0):

You add web components to a Java EE application in a package called a web application archive (WAR), which is a JAR similar to the package used for Java class libraries. A WAR usually contains other resources besides web components, including:

Server-side utility classes (database beans, shopping carts, and so on).
Static web resources (HTML, image, and sound files, and so on)
Client-side classes (applets and utility classes)

Check this link
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html